# Install nodejs using docker

Tags: node.js, centos, docker

I have tried the following to install nodes into a centos box but I get an error when it reaches ./configure

```
Step 6 : RUN tar -zxf node-v0.10.28-linux-x64.tar.gz
---> Running in ebc71472544d
---> c97289348900
Removing intermediate container ebc71472544d
Step 7 : RUN cd /node-v0.10.28-linux-x64
---> Running in 3470f862c586
---> 1771d01a5da0
Removing intermediate container 3470f862c586
Step 8 : RUN ./configure
 ---> Running in 16a811766136
/bin/sh: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile

```
#Install NodeJS
RUN cd /usr/src
RUN wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/node-v0.10.28-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxf node-v0.10.28-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN cd /node-v0.10.28-linux-x64
RUN ./configure
RUN make &&
RUN make install
```

Am I using the right way of installing nodes to centos using the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this isn't the whole Dockerfile, right? Otherwise you're missing at least a `FROM`.

Try to change the last 4 lines like that:

```
RUN cd /node-v0.10.28-linux-x64 && ./configure
RUN cd /node-v0.10.28-linux-x64 && make
RUN cd /node-v0.10.28-linux-x64 && make install
```

or like this

```
RUN cd /node-v0.10.28-linux-x64 && ./configure && make && make install
```

As far as I can tell, docker is running each `RUN` command as a separate shell, so just changing the directory won't be remembered in the next commands.

Here is an example Docker file to test this:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN cd /etc
RUN pwd
```

And here is the build log:

```
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 99ec81b80c55
Step 1 : RUN cd /etc
 ---> Running in a4c25ee340a8
 ---> 82ad93bdd18c
Removing intermediate container a4c25ee340a8
Step 2 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in f535178df40c
/
 ---> 495c68757268
```

[EDIT]

Another option is to use [WORKDIR](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#workdir), like this:

```
#Install NodeJS
WORKDIR /usr/src
ADD http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/node-v0.10.28-linux-x64.tar.gz .
RUN tar -zxf node-v0.10.28-linux-x64.tar.gz
WORKDIR node-v0.10.28-linux-x64
RUN ./configure
RUN make &&
RUN make install
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution using nvm:

```
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
RUN source $HOME/.bashrc && nvm install 12.14.1

RUN ln -s $HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node /usr/bin/node
RUN ln -s $HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
```